# Bootstrap row not aligning to right side of container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is driving me nuts and it seems like the solution is a simple one I am overlooking. I have a row of three images and it is my understanding that [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) takes care of the alignment of content.

Shouldn't the third image be aligned to the right side of the container with all three being equally spaced?

http://codepen.io/amits/pen/oxbjmd?editors=1100

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
  <img src="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <img src="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <img src="">
</div>
</div>
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Please change the title into a simple question.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the `.container`, and `.img-responsive` in `img` tag, plus you can have `.col-sm-*` for small devices and `.col-xs-*`  for extra small devices.

added `.col-xs-4` just for demo

take a look at the [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

```css
.container {
  border: red solid
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/1200/900">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/1200/900">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/1200/900">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```